# Suitable cloud service for storing web service output cache?

Tags: azure, cloud, outputcache, amazon-simpledb

I am developing a web service that mainly returns C# datatables.

It currently caches the output results into memcached cluster which is refreshed by another cache updater based on the internal messages.

Since those caches don't expire, it is crucial to have good failover etc...
As I go on with this, it gets quite difficult to ensure failover or reliable cache key control on this bare bone memcached cluster.

Also the scalability is becoming an important concern since this is going to be behind a large traffic portal.

So I am thinking if any cloud-based DB service (AWS SimpleDB, AWS MySQL or Azure?) can be a good candidate for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using AWS SimpleDB recently and it seems very good, if all you need is to dump large matrices of data. I was writing a script in python so I used the associated library and that lets you do things like:

```
 sdb = simpledb.SimpleDB('secret id') 
 forex_rates = sdb['forex'] # forex is the domain (table)
 forex_date = forex_rates['2011-01-01'] #get a row of the domain
 usd_rate = forex_date['USD']           #get a cell/datum
 forex_date['USD'] = '1.435'            #modify the cell
 forex_date['USD'].save()  # write the data back to the cloud
```

It's not a relational database as you probably already know.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. One question is that the value can not exceed 1024 bytes of string data according to the .Net example. This would be problematic since the serialized DataTable can easily exceed that.

Comment: Serialised how? If it ends up being a long string you can host it on S3 maybe. Nothing to stop you using it as a RESTful XML/JSON service. SimpleDB is terriffic for large matrices of simple data. Oh and be sure to accept/upvote one of the answers here.

Comment: DataTable will be serialized as an xml and will be quite long string.
Sample C# code AWS provided uses [ReplaceableAttribute Class](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_SimpleDB_Model_ReplaceableAttribute_WithValue.htm) and it says it can not exceed 1024 bytes. I feel like I'm not understanding _Attribute_ well enough.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Azure, have you looked into Azure AppFabric caching?  From a quick glance at your needs, it looks like it would provide you with a cloud-appropriate cache model.  Take a look

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/AppFabric/Overview/default.aspx#top

Comment: AppFabric Caching sounds like a good candidate for us but it's still in community preview stage.

Comment: How much of an issue this is will depend on when you're looking to release.  I don't think it's currently suitable for a production portal (not if it has high traffic as you suggest) as it has occasional significant outages while it is upgrade and there have been a few breaking changes.  But if you've got 6 months, it's perfectly good to develop on.

Comment: We only have 2~3 months to release. However, thank you for the tip.